# What would happen if I deleted the Ubuntu partition from OSX?

Tags: boot, mac

What would happen if I delete the Ubuntu partitions from Apple's Disk Utility? I read that the bootloader would stay on the drive and I wouldn't be able to delete it any more or something like that. What are the disadvantages of using Disk Utility instead of the Live USB?

Comment: Are you on an Apple computer and want to remove Ubuntu?

Comment: @Alvar there's something fundamentally wrong with that duplicated (windows != mac)

Comment: @Alvar again, there's something fundamentally wrong with that statement "What would happen if I deleted the Ubuntu partition **from OSX?**" meaning, while Ubuntu is not being used.

Answer (score 1):

You would no longer be able to access those partitions. Meaning, no booting Ubuntu, and no accessing any data that was on those partitions and depending how you installed GRUB, you could not boot OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer would not boot, you would see something like this error:

```
GRUB loading.
error: no such partition
grub rescue>
```

It might work if you follow the steps [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1631138?tstart=0), i.e.:

1. [Reset NVRAM/PRAM as in here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1379).
2. When you reboot, hold down the Option key and you should see OS X as one of the options. Boot into it and then in the System Preferences, under Startup Disk, simply click and select OS X as the default.
3. If **might** be safe to delete Ubuntu at this point if GRUB does not show on boot.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the Ubuntu partition, you will no longer be able to use Ubuntu. You will not just be able to boot OS X. When you ask for ***disadvantages***, that only you can answer. If you like Ubuntu, I'm not sure why you'd delete it to begin with. But other than that, you're just deleting the Ubuntu [Linux] operating system leaving yourself to only use OS X.